# internet sharing over ipsec

Tags: networking, internet, ipsec, strongswan

I try to connect my Windows 7 workstation to the Internet over ipsec tunnel.
I have:

```
192.168.88.251  - win7 workstation
192.168.88.1    - my mikrotik router
VPN_IPSEC       - my vpn with ipsec address
VPN_TEST        - my 2nd vpn for connectiviti testing
```

StrongSwan config on VPN_IPSEC:

```
config setup
 charondebug="ike 1, knl 1, cfg 0"
 uniqueids=no

conn ikev2-vpn
 auto=add
 compress=no
 type=tunnel
 keyexchange=ikev2
 fragmentation=yes
 forceencaps=yes

 ike=aes256-sha-modp1024
 esp=aes256-sha-modp1024
 dpdaction=clear
 dpddelay=300s
 rekey=no

 left=%any
 leftid=VPN_IPSEC_IP
 leftsendcert=always
 leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0

 right=%any
 rightid=%any
 authby=secret
 rightsubnet=192.168.88.251/24
 rightdns=8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
```

On the mikrotik side I have corresponding config

ipsec status command output:

```
ikev2-vpn[1]: ESTABLISHED 110 minutes ago, 
VPN_IPSEC_IP[VPN_IPSEC_IP]...MY_PUB_IP[MY_PUB_IP]
 ikev2-vpn{1}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, ESP SPIs: ca494e15_i 099301b9_o
 ikev2-vpn{1}:   0.0.0.0/0 === 192.168.88.251/32
```

Apparently my ipsec tunnel works correctly. 
On VPN_IPSEC I do ping  192.168.88.251, and I see pinging. 
At the same time
when on win7 I do ping 8.8.8.8, I see traffic in installed SA section on mikrotik, and if I create some firewall rules on VPN_IPSEC that operates with 192.168.88.251, I see matching counters grow.

On VPN_IPSEC I have this initial firewall config:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 936 packets, 92296 bytes)

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 483 packets, 29148 bytes)

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 306 packets, 30108 bytes)
```

Table NAT is the same: all accept

Now I now that encrypted traffic from win7 comes to VPN_IPSEC.
I want to now that it forwarded outside VPN_IPSEC.

On win7 I do

```
ping VPN_TEST
```

On VPN_IPSEC I do

```
tcpdump  -nni venet0 icmp
```

I see:

```
IP 192.168.88.251 > VPN_TEST_IP: ICMP echo request, id 512, seq 21277, length 40


IP 192.168.88.251 > VPN_TEST_IP: ICMP echo request, id 512, seq 49949, length 40
```

i.e no answer

now I add POSTROUTING rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.88.0/24 -o venet0 -j MASQUERADE

IP 192.168.88.251 > VPN_TEST_IP: ICMP echo request, id 25095, seq 301, length 64
IP 185.69.52.31 > VPN_TEST_IP: ICMP echo request, id 25095, seq 301, length 64
IP 192.168.88.251 > VPN_TEST_IP: ICMP echo request, id 25095, seq 302, length 64
IP 185.69.52.31 > VPN_TEST_IP: ICMP echo request, id 25095, seq 302, length 64
```

i.e., no answer, but i see that packets are masqueraded

At the same time on VPN_TEST I do:

```
tcpdump  -nni eth0 icmp
```

and I see no pings from my VPN_IPSEC, but I see random pings from over Internet hosts.

I also do on win7:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

And I get no reply.

At the same time when I do on VPN_IPSEC

```
ping VPN_TEST
```

I see all pings on both tcpdumps, and see reply

**i.e., traffic from my tunnel stays on VPN_IPSEC**

How it cat be??

How I can configure firewall on VPN_IPSEC properly.

UPD: I know  that for internet connection sharing I should create
masquerading and forwarding rules. Also I should have
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1. I already have it. And I have try many masquerading
and forwarding rules in the mix. NO RESULT.

At this time I only want see for now, that my pings from tunnel goes to my VPN_TEST, and comes back to VPN_IPSEC.

Comment: Are you sure the tunnel is up? Issue the `ipsec status` command on your VPN server and provide its output.

Comment: Please edit your question and add this information there, it’s hard to read in comments.

Comment: here my question on ServerFault:https://serverfault.com/questions/909878/ping-and-all-traffic-from-ipsec-tunnel-stay-inside-vpn-server

Comment: i include ipsec status to question

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in OpenVz  vps  limitations. When i run same ipsec tunnel on 
vps with **KVM** hipervisor, problem was solved.